# bootstrap select2 jump on control

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, jquery-select2, bootstrap-multiselect

We are using bootstrap script for our website. Here we have used bootstrap multiselect droupdown.

Please go through the below URL for more details.

URL: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Website scroll going bottom or middle of the page instead web page have to show top header content.  This is happening only in chrome browser.

I am not able to track ether it is chrome issue or bootstrap.

Please help me for the same

Comment: If you are using Jquery UI please check that also, And please add working fiddle that we can help you

Comment: well one thing you are missing (but doesnt solve the problem) is placing an active class on your nav per click , like $('.nav li a').on('click', function() {

    $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});